# Calling A Method That Was Just Created. Error Calculating Max Stack Value

Tags: c#, vb.net, instructions, opcodes, dnlib

so I was fooling around with DNLIB recently, and I was trying to add methods to a .net file. I got the methods from a previously compiled file, so basically, I was trying to mimic the method.

There are 3 methods: GetTheTypes, InvokeIt, and InvokeCall.

Firstly, I had to create the methods GetTheTypes and InvokeIt because InvokeCall calls both the GetTheTypes method and the InvokeIt method. So I added those methods, and they were added perfectly. It compiled and saved, and I was able to see them in a reflector/ILSpy with no problem. Note: when I add the methods, I have a check to see if they should be static or non-static, so that is not an issue. They are also all public methods.

Then, I wanted to add the InvokeCall method. So I did the same thing I did for the other methods, opened the methods I wanted mimicked in ILSpy, then basically copied all of the instructions and local variables into a new CilBody which were added to the InvokeCall method that I was mimicking. The only problem was it threw an error saying **"Error Calculating Max Stack Value"**. The weird thing was, if I changed the OPCode from Call to NewObj, it compiled fine. But that is not what I want to do. What I want to do throws the error mentioned above.

Here is the code I use to add the instruction:

```
cBody.Instructions.Add(OpCodes.Call.ToInstruction(_getTheTypesMethod))
```

The **_getThetypesMethod** variable is defined as a **MethodDefUser** and consists of the method I created ealier and compiled just fine. I have also tried this:

```
cBody.Instructions.Add(OpCodes.Call.ToInstruction(t.Asm.Import(_getTheTypesMethod)))
```

That also did not work. I have also tried to get the DeclaringType of the method as well, then Finding the method like this:

```
cBody.Instructions.Add(OpCodes.Call.ToInstruction(t.Asm.Import(_getTheTypesMethod.GetDeclaringType().FindMethod("GetTheTypes")))
```

That didn't work either.

So if anyone has any suggestions as to how to call a method that was just created, please tell me. I've been trying to find out how to fix this problem for the last day or so, with no prevail. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was my MethodSig was wrong. I was referencing a static method with a instance MethodSig. I only had a check when creating the method for the method attributes, not the creation attributes.